# How can I change the stripe checkout form with a sign up or login form

Tags: python, django

My ecommerce website is set such that it's only through stripe checkout an order is created. Is there an option to replace the checkout form with a sign up or login form for new and returning clients respectively.

Comment: Do you still want to perform a Stripe purchase? If not, just create an ordinary login form from scratch.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. But [so] isn't for general design questions. It's for questions about fixing specific code that you've written.

Comment: About Stripe checkout, it's a part of your checkout flow, login/sign up also a part of that when you consider to add these forms. But after all, you have to design your checkout flow and organize your forms based on the flow